# Order SQL database using RSQLlite and DBI

Tags: r, dbi, rsqlite

I would like to order a SQL database by rowname using R. I am able to fetch the ordered results:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(con, "cars", mtcars, temporary = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
dbReadTable(con, "cars")

res <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY rowname ASC')
dbFetch(res)
```

but I would like to order the SQL database itself. If I try the below code nothing happens:

```
dbExecute(con, 'SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY rowname ASC')
dbReadTable(con, "cars")
```

Comment: If you are trying to impose an order on stored rows, give up, SQLite doesn't support that (nor does any other sane database).  If you are trying to order rows in the result of a database query, your question could be a bit clearer.

Comment: What is the reason for this? Updating, deleting, or editing rows is no problem. Why not changing the order?

Comment: Why do you want to change the order in which the data is stored? Maybe there is a xy problem here.

Comment: It is a dynamic database where users can add, delete and update there entries. After each change I want the data to be properly sorted again.

Comment: @Nivel But why do you want the data sorted *in the database*. With most RDBMS the physical layout of the data storage is beyond your control. So if you need a certain order, you have to specify that when requesting the data.  BTW, if you are answering to a question you should address the poster explicitly. Otherwise they might get notified.

Comment: One of the reasons RDBMS don't order rows in tables is theoretical, the relational model doesn't recognise the concept of row order, two relations containing the same rows are the same.  Other, practical reasons apply too: Which order should rows be kept in ?  How much of an overhead are you prepared to accept on insertion, deletion and updates to maintain row order ?